# Oracle select statement

Tags: oracle, select

In mysql I can write a query like "Select a.field1 > a.field2 from a" and I will get a result set of 0's and 1's

I tried writing a similar query in oracle but it doesn't work.  How can I get a similar result set with oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
Select CASE WHEN a.field1 > a.field2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END from a
```